# How to retrieve a value/url?

Tags: c#

I apologize in advance as I have not used visual studio much before and I used a template for the most part to create the code below. But I really need some help.

I'm trying to generate a report from a system using visual studio through an API. The code below works and doesn't give me any errors when debugging, but I need to find a way to retrieve the reportURL variable at the end (the report is generated with the specifications below and I should receive a URL to download the report). I am building as a windows application.

Is there anything like console.log or console.writeline in visual studio I can use? Or can I output it to a textbox of some kind? (Again, I am building as a windows form and not a console application). Can anyone help me figure out some kind of code I can use to retrieve the URL based on what is provided below? (Please be detailed if possible as I am still getting used to the program). Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ReportsApplication2
{
using ServiceReference1;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReportExecutionServiceClient client = new ReportExecutionServiceClient();
        ReportSubmission submissionRequest = new ReportSubmission();
        ReportSubmissionResponse submissionResponse = new ReportSubmissionResponse();
        PollReportResponse pollResponse = new PollReportResponse();
        WebMediaReportRequest webRepReq = new WebMediaReportRequest();
        UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials();
        DateFilter dateFilter = new DateFilter();

        userCredentials.UserName = "xxxxx";
        userCredentials.Password = "xxxxx";
        submissionRequest.UserCredentials = userCredentials;
        submissionRequest.DeveloperToken = "xxxxxx";

        dateFilter.DateFilterType = DateFilterType.Total;
        dateFilter.RelativeDateRange = RelativeDateRange.LastMonth;
        webRepReq.Columns = new WebMediaReportColumn[2] { WebMediaReportColumn.MediaPlanName, WebMediaReportColumn.Impressions };

        List<WebMediaFilter> webRepFilterList = new List<WebMediaFilter>();
        WebMediaFilter webRepFilter = new WebMediaFilter();

        webRepFilter.Column =   WebMediaReportFilter.ClientGUID;
        webRepFilter.Values =    new string[1] {"xxxxxx"};
        webRepFilterList.Add(webRepFilter);

        webRepFilter = new WebMediaFilter();
        webRepFilter.Column = WebMediaReportFilter.BuyGUID;
        webRepFilter.Values = new string[1] { "xxxxxxxx" };
        webRepFilterList.Add(webRepFilter);

        webRepReq.ReportName = "test";
        webRepReq.Filters = webRepFilterList.ToArray();
        webRepReq.Format = FormatType.CSV;
        webRepReq.DateFilter = dateFilter;

        submissionRequest.ReportRequest = webRepReq;
        submissionResponse = client.SubmitReport(submissionRequest);

        string reportURL = string.Empty;
        do    { // Loop until report complete or failed

        PollReportRequest pollRequest = new PollReportRequest();
        pollRequest.DeveloperToken =     "xxxxxxx";
        pollRequest.UserCredentials =     userCredentials;
        pollRequest.ReportId =            submissionResponse.ReportId;


        pollResponse = client.PollReport(pollRequest);

        reportURL = pollResponse.Url;

         } while ((pollResponse.Status != ReportStatus.Failed) || ((pollResponse.Status != ReportStatus.Complete)));

    }//end
```

Comment: Are you printing it out only as debugging information during development, or is this a runtime feature for the end-user? If the latter, then Console.WriteLine() won't do the job, you'll need to use a Winforms approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Winforms, the simplest approach to show messages is MessageBox.Show():

```
  MessageBox.Show(reportURL);
```

It will block the program until you click Ok.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you want to output debug info during development, then Console.WriteLine() will work:

```
Console.WriteLine(reportURL);
```

It will show in the Output window. If you don't see that, go to the main menu in Visual Studio and select View -> Output, while in debug mode.

Console.WriteLine() will only work within Visual Studio for a Winforms app; after deploying it, the console window doesn't show, so you'll need to show it via a GUI method.

If you need to output it at runtime, either drag a TextBox from the toolbox onto your main form, and do:

```
textBox.Text = reportURL;
```

If you can't show it on the main form, then you may want to create your own custom message dialog that includes a TextBox and show it with ShowDialog()

Comment: Thanks! This works and I get a URL, but I'm unable to copy it directly from the message box (I have to type it manually in the address bar based on the message that pops up). Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: technically, ctrl+c while any windows messagebox is open and has focus should contain the whole text of the messagebox (including title and buttons)

Answer (score 2):

You actually already know what you need.  The [Console.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will write anything you want to the Console.

While you are debugging in Visual Studio, you can view the Console window by turning on the "Output" window.  You can find it in the `View` menu

Even though you are writing a WinForms application, this will still write to the Output window while debugging.  It can be an effective tool when debugging, but of course, when you actually publish the application, the command will be meaningless since you won't have a Console to write too.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `Console.WriteLine`.